# Python path issue while importing my own modules. What is the best way to go about it?

Tags: python

I've created python modules but they are in different directories.

```
/xml/xmlcreator.py
/tasklist/tasks.py
```

Here, tasks.py is trying to import xmlcreator but both are in different paths. One way to do it is include xmlcreator.py in the Pythonpath. But, considering that I'll be publishing the code, this doesn't seem the right way to go about it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder). Thus, how do I include xmlcreator or rather any module that might be written by me which would be in various directories and sub directories?

Comment: Have you tried setting the python path? either `sys.path.append("/xml")` or extend `%PYTHONPATH%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to publish both modules separately or together in one package?

If the former, then you'll probably want to have your users install your xml module (I'd call it something else :) so that it is, by default, already on Python's path, and declare it as a dependency of the tasklist module.

If both are distributed as a bundle, then [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) seem to be the best option, since you can control where the paths are relative to each other.

Comment: Yep, just give the library a proper name that doesn't clash with anything already existing :)

Comment: Agreed. And as a corollary, if you'll be sharing that module among various applications, then I'd definitely suggest my first suggestion.

Comment: Er, right. :) I guess I meant that it would be a good idea to distribute the modules separately if, say, the xml module will be used by othe modules.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create subpackages in a single top-level package that you define. You then ship these together in one package.  If you are using setuptools/Distribute and you want to distribute them separately then you may also define a "namspace package" that the packages will be installed in. You don't need to use any ugly sys.path hacks.

Make a directory tree like this:

```
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/xml/__init__.py
mypackage/xml/xmlcreator.py
mypackage/tasklist/__init__.py
mypackage/tasklist/tasks.py
```

The `__init__.py` files may be empty. They define the directory to be a package that Python will search in.

Except if you want to use namespace packages the `mypackage/__init__.py` should contains:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

And your `setup.py` file contain:

```
...
namespace_packages=["mypackage"],
...
```

Then in your code:

```
from mypackage.xml import xmlcreator
from mypackage.tasklist import tasks
```

Will get them anywhere you need them. You only need to make one name globally unique in this case, the `mypackage` name.

For developing the code you can put the package in "develop mode", by doing

```
python setup.py develop --user
```

This will set up the local python environment to look for your package in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

When I start a new Python project, I immediately write its `setup.py` and [declare my Python modules/packages](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#basic-use), so that then I just do:

`python setup.py develop`

and everything gets magically added to my PYTHONPATH. If you do it from a virtualenv it's even better, since you don't need to install it system-wide.

Here's more about it:

http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#development-mode